# Lotus Notes WebService Consumer populate Array XSD_STRING

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm having some real trouble here regarding a Lotus Notes webservice consumer (written in lotus script).
The thing is that I'm sending an array (as a Class) to type `XSD_Anytype`, see below.

```
***************************************
**** Snippet from WebService **********
%INCLUDE "lsxsd.lss"
Class ArrayOfString_n1 As XSD_ANYTYPE

  Public string() As XSD_STRING

  Sub NEW
  End Sub


End Class

Const n1 = "http://xx.xx.x.xx/XXX/Statistic/Account/"
Class UserIDSoap_n1 As PortTypeBase

  Sub NEW
    Call Service.Initialize ("HttpxxxxxxxXXXStatisticAccountUserID", _
    "UserID.UserIDSoap", "http://xx.xx.x.xx/XXX/Statistic/Account/Account.asmx", _
    "UserIDSoap_n1")

  End Sub

  Function setAccount(IV_list As ArrayOfString_n1) As ArrayOfString_n1
    Set setAccount = Service.Invoke("setAccount", IV_list)
  End Function

End Class



Class XXXsetAccount As UserIDSoap_n1 

  Sub NEW
    Call Service.Initialize ("HttpxxxxxxxXXXStatisticAccountUserID", _
    "UserID.UserIDSoap", "http://xx.xx.x.xx/XXX/Statistic/Account/Account.asmx", _
    "UserIDSoap_n1")

End Sub

  Function setAccount(IV_list As ArrayOfString_n1) As ArrayOfString_n1
    Set setAccount = Service.Invoke("setAccount", IV_list)
  End Function

End Class



**** Snippet from WebService **********
***************************************
```

In my program I'm trying to populate an array of the class above.
When I assign a value to the array, Im able to send and get correct answer back from the called URI.

My problem is assigning different values to the array.
It seems that `mmm` is a reference and therefore it alters the whole array (`LA_String`).

```
***************************************
**** Snippet from program *************

Dim mmm         As XSD_STRING 
Dim LA_string   As New ArrayOfString_n1()
ReDim Preserve LA_string.String( CInt( view.Entrycount ) - 1 )

Dim i As Integer

i = 0
Do While Not ( dok Is Nothing )
  mmm.setValueFromString( dok.FieldWithValue( 0 ) )
  set LA_string.string(i) = mmm
  i = i + 1
  Set dok = View.GetNextDocument( dok )
Loop

**** Snippet from program *************
***************************************
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `mmm` is reference, so you need to create new `XSD_String` object each time in your cycle.
Here is example:

```
Dim mmm         As XSD_STRING 
Dim LA_string   As New ArrayOfString_n1()
ReDim Preserve LA_string.String( CInt( view.Entrycount ) - 1 )

Dim i As Integer

i = 0
Do While Not ( dok Is Nothing )
  Set mmm = New XSD_STRING() ' <= Create new object here.
  mmm.setValueFromString( dok.FieldWithValue( 0 ) )
  set LA_string.string(i) = mmm
  i = i + 1
  Set dok = View.GetNextDocument( dok )
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much :-).

Actually I tried this approach - somehow - , but I must have done something slightly different/wrong, as your solution works 100%.

If Im supposed to give your answer a rating, Im not aware of how, so please forgive me in that case.
Again thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: @LarsHansen You should have enough reputation to gain some [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) as voting, flaging, etc.

Comment: @LarsHansen By marking as useful comment you claim that the comment is useful. There are no reputation from this action. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) is the list of actions on which you can gain/lose your reputation.